# update array in nested array without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Below code doesn't look good to me, as I have to declare a temp variable, any shorter code to achieve the same result?

```
handleChange = (e, index1, innerIndex) => {
  const temp_values = this.state.values
    temp_values.map((value, index) => {
      if (index === innerIndex) {
        temp_values[index].args[index1] = e.target.value
      }
    })
    this.setState({
      values: temp_values
    })
}
```

Comment: You *are* mutating in that code. `.values` refers to an object, `temp_values` is nothing more than another reference to that same object in memory. You also definitely shouldn't use `.map` if you aren't using the resulting mapped array.

Comment: ya I know above code work but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify it like this:

```
handleChange = (e, index1, innerIndex) => {
  this.setState({
    values: this.state.values.map((value, index) => {
      const args = [].concat(value.args);
      if (index === innerIndex) {
        args[index1] = e.target.value;
      }

      return {
        ...value,
        args,
      };
    }),
  });
}
```